# Strip metadata from files in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, image, metadata

I'm working on a React/ Typescript application.
The user can upload different filetypes (pictures, word-docs, pdf..), and i need to remove all identifying metadata from these files, before they are sent to the server.

I've read about no-EXIF, and that might be enough handle the images.
But what about text documents, such as word-docs, pdf and the like.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, every file type has its own metadata implementation. So there will be separate solutions, I guess.

Comment: appreciate the answer, thanks.